# Using VBA, How can I replace a substring in a text file's line that contains a specific String

Tags: vba, ms-access

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBza1.png)

What I need to do, is to replace the strings highlighted in yellow with a custom text, only in the line that contains the string highlighted in blue, and leave the other lines untouched.
Something like this:

```
For Each line in File
  If line contains "39202|A|92"
    File = Replace(line, "3Gc%C<a>", "text1", , 1)
    File = Replace(line, "3Gc%C<b>", "text2", , 1)
  Exit For
  End If
```

*Thank you in advance*

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to check strings and standard VBA commands for text files:

```
Option Explicit

Sub repFile()
    Const fPath = "test_in.txt" ' in the same directory as thisworkbook
    
    Dim fn As Integer, buf As String, out As String, re As Object
    
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\d{5}\|[ABD]\|\d{2}"
    End With
    
    fn = FreeFile
    Open fPath For Input As #fn
    Do While Not EOF(fn)
        Input #fn, buf
        If re.Test(buf) Then
            buf = Replace(buf, "3Gc%C<a>", "text1", vbTextCompare)
            buf = Replace(buf, "3Gc%C<b>", "text2", vbTextCompare)
        End If
        out = out & buf & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close #fn
    
    fn = FreeFile
    Open Replace(fPath, "_in", "_out") For Output As #fn
    Print #fn, out
    Close #fn
End Sub
```